# Download a file without name using Python

Tags: python, download

I want to download a file, there is a hyper link in html page which does not include the file name and extension. How can I download the file using python?
For example the link is http://1.1.1.1:8080/tank-20/a/at_download/file,
but whenever I click on it the file will download and open with browser.

Comment: the link does not work. What you can do is open the developer tools and see the request your browser did in the network tab. From that you can copy the request as curl, and then implement the request in any other way you want.

Comment: the `file` part of your URL seems to be the file name. There is no requirement for a file to have an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use python requests to get the body of the response and write to file, this is essentially what the browser is doing when you click the link.

Try the below:

```py
import requests

# define variables
request_url = "http://1.1.1.1:8080/tank-20/a/at_download/file"
output_file = "output.txt"

# send get request
response = requests.get(request_url)

# use 'with' to write to file
with open(output_file, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(response.content)
    fh.close()
```

Comment: this code does not work, the file is pdf, but in other site works!, it is possible to set a attribute in this site with its developer to prevent using a program to download, if yes is there a solution?